# invalid type argument of ‘->’

Tags: c, pointers, structure

i am getting error as  "invalid type argument of ‘->’ " on the below two marked lines
please suggest how to correct it

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct arr{
    int distance;
    int vertex;
};

struct heap{
    struct arr * array;

     int count; //# of elements
     int capacity;// size of heap
     int heapType; // min heap or max heap
};


int main(){
    int i;
    struct heap * H=(struct heap *)malloc(sizeof(struct heap));
    H->array=(struct arr *)malloc(10*sizeof(struct arr));

    H->array[0]->distance=20;//error

    i=H->array[0]->distance;//error

    printf("%d",i);
}
```

Comment: `H->array` contains 10 `struct arr`, not 10 `struct arr *`. So there's no need for the extra dereferencing. The first line should be `H->array[0].distance = 20;`

Comment: [You do not need to cast the result of malloc.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @Praetorian - Why are you answering the question in a comment and not as an actual answer?

Comment: @pzaenger I'd better say: **DO NOT** cast the result of malloc.

Comment: @Andrew To gain comment rep, of course! :P I didn't think that terse comment was worthy of an answer, and didn't have time to type a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The left argument of `->` must be a pointer. `H->array[0]` is a structure, not a pointer to a structure. So you should use the `.` operator to access a member:

```
H->array[0].distance = 20;
i = H->array[0].distance;
```

or combine them:

```
i = H->array[0].distance = 20;
```

BTW, in C you should *not* cast the result of `malloc()`. `malloc()` returns `void*`, and C automatically coerces this to the target type. If you forget to `#include` the declaration of `malloc()`, the cast will suppress the warning you should get. This isn't true in C++, but you usually should prefer `new` rather than `malloc()` in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The subscript implicitly dereferences the `array` member.  If `array` has type `struct arr *`, then `array[0]` has type `struct arr` (remember that `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`);